# Python: string is escaped when creating a tuple

Tags: python, tuples

I have the following code:

```
string = "ad\23e\4x{\s"
data = (string,)
```

When I print the data my string in the tuple has an extra slash for each slash a total of 6 back slashes.

How can I avoid the extra back slashes?

Answer (score 4):

The object `data` is a tuple. When you print a tuple, Python call `repr` for each element. If you want to format it another way, you have to do the conversion yourself.

```
>>> s = "ad\23e\4x{\s"
>>> d = (s,)
>>> print d
('ad\x13e\x04{\\s',)
>>> print '(%s,)' % (', '.join('"%s"' % _ for _ in d))
("adex{\s")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm wanting to format the string in the tuple like so: `code` "ad\23e\4x{\s"
`code`

Answer (score 1):

Those extra backslashes aren't actually in your string, they are just how Python *represents* strings (the idea being that you could paste that back into a program and it would work). It's doing that because the tuple's `__str__()` implementation calls `repr()` on each item. If you `print string` or `print data[0]` you will see what's *actually* in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
In [11]: string = r'ad\23e\4x{\s'

In [12]: string
Out[12]: 'ad\\23e\\4x{\\s'

In [13]: print string
ad\23e\4x{\s

In [14]: data=(string,)

In [15]: data
Out[15]: ('ad\\23e\\4x{\\s',)

In [16]: print data
('ad\\23e\\4x{\\s',)

In [17]: print data[0]
ad\23e\4x{\s
```